# How to turn off a safari shortcut

Tags: keyboard, safari, shortcut

I have been looking around to turn off "CMD + , (comma)" opening password manager in Safari but there appears to be no option to do so (maybe I missed it). The same shortcut is used as subscript shortcut in Google Docs and it is really annoying during essays. Does anyone knows how to do such thing?

Thank you beforehand!

PS: The same question is marked as duplicate but the answer is not relevant.

Comment: Don’t re-ask the same question, it makes it really confusing for future visitors trying to find the one right answer. Questions when edited go into the reopen queue for review by the community for reopening, please edit your original question with details about why the linked duplicate didn’t resolve your problem.